# get all docs where diff beetwen current timestamp and some column with nanoseconds value more some some interval

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb version 4.4.3 and I got in some collection exist structure with data - `ts` column with
nanoseconds value, like `1.6134264584976e+18`. My goal to get all docs where current timestamp - `ts` >= 25min
What I found
{$toDate: '$ts'} convert my to milisend

```
db.getCollection('device_heartbeat').aggregate( [ {
   $project: {
      date: {$toDate: '$ts'}
   }
} 
]
)
```

result

```
"date" : Date(1613426458497597952)
```

how to add condition to that query ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem,  this is query

```
db.getCollection('device_heartbeat').aggregate([
    {$match: { $expr:  { $gt: [ { $subtract: [ {$toLong: new Date()}, { $divide: [ {$toLong: {$toDate: '$ts'}} , 1000000 ] } ] }, 1500 ] }}},
    {$project: {
        diff: { $subtract: [ {$toLong: new Date()}, { $divide: [ {$toLong: {$toDate: '$ts'}} , 1000000 ] } ] }
        }}
    ])
```